# passing multiple queries to view with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to build a forum with Codeigniter.

So far i have the forums themselves displayed and the threads displayed, based on the creating dynamic news tutorial.

But that is 2 different pages, i need to obviously display them into one page, like this:

```
Forum 1
- thread 1
- thread 2
- thread 3 
Forum 2
- thread 1
- thread 2 
etc.
```

And then the next step is obviously to display all the posts in a thread. Most likely with some pagination going on. But that is for later.

For now i have the forum controller (slimmed version):

```
<?php
class Forum extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('forum_model');
        $this->lang->load('forum');
        $this->lang->load('dutch');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['forums'] = $this->forum_model->get_forums();

        $data['title'] = $this->lang->line('title');
        $data['view'] = $this->lang->line('view');

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('forum/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

    public function view($slug)
    {
        $data['forum_item'] = $this->forum_model->get_forums($slug);

        if (empty($data['forum_item']))
        {
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = $data['forum_item']['title'];

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('forum/view', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

}
?>
```

And the forum_model (also slimmed down)

```
<?php
class Forum_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_forums($slug = FALSE)
    {
        if ($slug === FALSE)
        {
            $query= $this->db->get('forum');
            return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('forum', array('slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }

        public function get_threads($forumid, $limit, $offset)
    {
            $query = $this->db->get_where('thread', array('forumid', $forumid), $limit, $offset);
            return $query->result_array();
    }


}
?>
```

And the view file

```
<?php foreach ($forums as $forum_item): ?>

    <h2><?=$forum_item['title']?></h2>
    <div id="main">
        <?=$forum_item['description']?>
    </div>
    <p><a href="forum/<?php echo $forum_item['slug'] ?>"><?=$view?></a></p>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Now that last one, i would like to have something like this:

```
<?php foreach ($forums as $forum_item): ?>

    <h2><?=$forum_item['title']?></h2>
    <div id="main">
        <?=$forum_item['description']?>
    </div>
    <?php foreach ($threads as $thread_item): ?>

    <h2><?php echo $thread_item['title'] ?></h2>
    <p><a href="thread/<?php echo $thread_item['slug'] ?>"><?=$view?></a></p>

    <?php endforeach ?>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

**But the question is, how do i get the model to return like a double query to the view, so that it contains both the forums and the threads within each forum.**

I tried to make a foreach loop in the get_forum function, but when i do this:

```
public function get_forums($slug = FALSE)
    {
        if ($slug === FALSE)
        {
            $query= $this->db->get('forum');
            foreach ($query->row_array() as $forum_item)
            {
                $thread_query=$this->get_threads($forum_item->forumid, 50, 0);
            }
            return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('forum', array('slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
```

i get the error

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: models/forum_model.php

Line Number: 16
```

I hope anyone has some good tips, thanks!

Lenny

**EDIT**********

Thanks for the feedback.

I have been puzzling and this seems to work now :)

```
    $query= $this->db->get('forum');
        foreach ($query->result() as $forum_item)
        {
            $forum[$forum_item->forumid]['title']=$forum_item->title;
            $thread_query=$this->db->get_where('thread', array('forumid' => $forum_item->forumid), 20, 0);
            foreach ($thread_query->result() as $thread_item)
            {
                $forum[$forum_item->forumid]['thread'][]=$thread_item->title;
            }
        }
        return $forum;
    }
```

What is now next, is how to display this multidimensional array in the view, with foreach statements....

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: Show Your code on line number 16 in forum_model.

Comment: the line was:               $thread_query=$this->get_threads($forum_item->forumid, 50, 0);

Comment: i think the problem was the call of another function, maybe done incorrectly. Thanks anyways. This issue is solved now.

Comment: In almost every forum I can think of the only thread you'd ever need to get on the forum view is the last posted one, why are you trying to return all of your forums and all of their threads together? Seems counter-intuitive to me. Standard forums are laid out like this. Main page, main forums (sometimes their sub forums listed) and the latest posted thread. Forum page, list sub forums and their latest posted thread. Sub forum pages, list threads and last post time/user

Comment: hey thanks, i agree with you. I will end up only showing like the latest threads or maybe not even one. But still, there is a "double query" needed. A multi level array, with the forums and then the latest thread. SO in my opinion, the function will still be the same, dont you think?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `row_array()` hence your error, change your get_forums() to:

```
 $thread_query=$this->get_threads($forum_item['forumid'], 50, 0);
```

But I believe you should actually be using `result_array()` since you want a list of all forums.